# Local variable in nagios config

Tags: nagios

Is it possible to have local variables in Nagios config files?

I'm probably doing something a little "wrong", but I think this will fit my specific usecase the best.

I have lots of VERY different services I need to monitor. They might change independently of each other or they might stay the same. I know I can use host groups and add my services to monitor a given hostgroup, and then add hosts to that group and remove them as needed.

But honestly I just wanted to define those 5-6 services I need to monitor, right beside my host definition in the servers folder. This works great, but I have this cumbersome job everytime I copy the file to monitor a new host, that I need to input the IP and redefine the hostname all the way down (beside making tweaks where needed).

Can't I somehow define the hostname at the top of the config file and have it cascade to all the service definition in the same config file? That would really help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a template, and then have the hosts use that template. Example from the nagios documentation:

```
define host{
    host_name       bighost1
    check_command       check-host-alive
    notification_options    d,u,r
    max_check_attempts  5
    name            hosttemplate1
    }
define host{
    host_name       bighost2
    max_check_attempts  3
    use         hosttemplate1
    }
```

When you are asking for per-file variables. This wont work. Nagios has no concept of individual config files. It just takes all the objects. So if you define a macro like `$MYIPMACRO:192.168.0.1$` this macro is true for ALL objects, your entire nagios configuration. I think icinga2 can do what you want to achieve and is compatible with nagios check plugins.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I want to make a variable LOCAL to the config file it's in, so I can have multiple define host {} and define service {} in the same file, and when copying the file to add a new host, I can just update the host_name in one place, instead of having to go through all the services.

Your solution would just move the "problem" to the template, and I would have to create multiple templates. :(

Comment: @Henrik I see. That is not possible. See edit. Of course you could just search/replace the IP or whatever in the document, and possible make a bashscript to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response anyway. I figured I'm "holding it wrong" but your comment/answer got me to learn "sed" real quick. I must admit I'm probably not the greatest Linux admin not having known that before, but yeah.. Sometimes you are SO focused on making ONE specific tool work, that you forget you could just use something else. Thanks for the response and enjoy the weekend.

Comment: @henrik Live and learn, it's what this site is about.